# @test annotation is there but in result no test is found

Tags: java, selenium, testng

The image of my code:

[image]

Console error

[image]

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Aren't both the images the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to run an testng suite and not a single test case.
Hence the error states it's comming from TestNG.

If you want to run only a single class with tests, simply use your IDE to perform a run option on that class.

If you want to run a whole test suite with testng, you need to configure your testng.xml file to include all your classes or test methods. F.e:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite example suite 1" >
  <test name="Test name example" >
    <classes>
      <class name="mainPage.For_LM"/>
    </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```